# Swift 3 - How to use enum raw value as NSNotification.Name?

Tags: xcode, enums, nsnotificationcenter, swift3

I'm using Xcode 8 beta 5 and I'm trying to setup an enum of notifications like this

```
enum Notes: String {
  case note1
  case note2
}
```

Then trying to use them as the notification names

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notes.note1.rawValue as NSNotification.Name,
                                object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
```

But I'm getting an error.

`Cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'NSNotification.Name'`

Is there a work around, or am I missing something? It works in Xcode 7.3.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here you go, Use Swift 3 & Xcode 8.0

```
enum Notes: String {

    case note1 = "note1"
    case note2 = "note2"

    var notification : Notification.Name  {
        return Notification.Name(rawValue: self.rawValue )
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notes.note2.notification ,object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

Another way

```
import UIKit

extension Notification.Name
{
    enum MyNames
    {
        static let Hello = Notification.Name(rawValue: "HelloThere")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.MyNames.Hello ,object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is no reason to put 'enum MyNames' inside 'extension Notification.Name'. It just makes no sense.

Answer (score 24):

I am doing this way, For me this is more simple way to manage Notification names.

**Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.0**

**Using extension** of Notification.Name, we can define static names inside that as following.

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let newPasscodeSet = Notification.Name("newPasscodeSet")
    static let userLoggedIn = Notification.Name("userLoggedIn")
    static let notification3 = Notification.Name("notification3")
}
```

We can use that names like this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.newPasscodeSetAction), name: .newPasscodeSet, object: nil)
 }

 func newPasscodeSetAction() {
     // Code Here.
 }
```

Hope this simple way helpful for you.

Comment: The advantage of enum is all the cases will have `Notification.Name` type by default. It means if you add `extension Notification.Name: ExpressibleByStringLiteral` then it simplifies code a lot

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, there was no type `NSNotification.Name` in Swift 2.2.1/SDKs bundled in Xcode 7.3.1, so I'm curious how you have made it work.

Anyway you need to write something like this if you want to utilize your enum:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(Notes.note1.rawValue),
                                object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
```

---

By the way, my best recommendation to define your own `Notification.Name` is using extension which defines static properties:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let note1 = NSNotification.Name("note1")
    static let note2 = NSNotification.Name("note2")
}
```

(It's a little bit longer than enum..., but) you can use it like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .note1,
                                object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
```

Comment: You're right. There isn't `NSNotification.Name` in Swift 2.2. I meant that I could just assign the notification name with the raw value. I should have been more clear.

Comment: @D.Greg, thanks for clarification. As you know Swift betas are so rapidly changing, I was afraid I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe another approach in swift 4.2

```
extension Notification.Name{
   struct RecordListNotification {
        static let recordListDidChange:Notification.Name = Notification.Name("recordListDidChange")
        static let recordListTimeDidChange = Notification.Name("recordListTimeDidChange")
    }
}
```

and then

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.RecordListNotification.recordListTimeDidChange, object: nil)
```

also to avoid verbose:

```
typealias RecordListNotification = Notification.Name.RecordListNotification
```

And it can be used:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: RecordListNotification.recordListTimeDidChange, object: nil)
```

Comment: thank you. You can also create and struct and define static Notification names